# Windows 2008 server grinds to a halt under medium/heavy network traffic

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-attached-storage, truecrypt, server-crashes

I have a nas running Windows server 2008 standard sp2 (x86) and in the past few days it has started crashing whenever there was more then only light network traffic going on.

It happens when:
- Downloading torrents (both in µtorrent and vuze)
- Copying files to and from the nas using teracopy

The nas has 4 disks, which are not in a raid configuration but are encrypted using truecrypt. First I thought one of the disks went bad, so I checked all of them using hdtune, but no bad sectors were found. It seems to be quite mysterious problem. With only light traffic, just watching some movies off it etc,... it runs perfectly fine.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "crashing"?

Comment: Anything pertinent in event viewer?  Does the server lock up?  Does it reboot?  What?

Comment: Question says "Grind to a halt". Description says crash. What do you mean?

Comment: All file transfers slow down until they stop and then the host just dissapears. I manage it through remote desktop, and it just starts to stutter until the connection is lost. Event viewer shows nothing out of the ordinary :s

Comment: Have you checked your traffic? I'm not an expert at wireshark, but I've seen streaming media really hit a network hard, more or less torrents. Do you have this on any kind of different subnet, or a vlan for QOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SysInternals [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) will help identify your problem..